# AdMob in iOS with UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, admob

I'm using the latest Xcode (4.4.1) and developing for iOS 5.1. I am utilizing the bottom tab bar interface provided by Apple. One of the tabs uses a UIWebView that utilizes the full screen space. When I try to add a standard banner provided by AdMob, it does not add a banner at all. I was following along with: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals. Code attached below

About.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface About : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

    // Declare one as an instance variable
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

About.m

```
#import "About.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"
#import "constants.h"

@implementation About

@synthesize webView;
//@synthesize bannerView = bannerView_;

+ (void)initialize {
    // Set user agent (the only problem is that we can't modify the User-Agent later in the program)
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:UserAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = ([IsBeta isEqualToString: @"true"]) ? @"http://beta.wouldyouratherapp.com/questions/index/0/1" : @"http://wouldyouratherapp.com/questions/index/0/1";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]; NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MyAdUnitID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

Yes, I have added all the frameworks already, and MyAdUnitID is already defined in the constants file, so everything SHOULD be working, but I guess I am missing something. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding the `bannerView_`, you'll have to decrease the height of your `webView` accordingly to make room for the `bannerView_`. Since the origin of the ad looks like its at (0,0), you probably want something similar to this in your `adView:DidReceiveAd`: callback:

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake (0, bannerView_.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I have figured out that it wasn't loading because I set my own custom UserAgent. I will need to look into this issue now...